# Why does a bool array have a int type output that is not 1 or 0?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

```c
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>

int main(void) {
    char ch[] = "test";
    bool X[32];
    char * pos = (char *)X;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        pos[i] = ch[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", X[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

output:
116

There are both int type number that is not 1 or 0 and bool type 'false' in the array.

As the following picture.

VS code debug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4e4i.png)

Comment: Please copy&paste text to your question as text instead of showing screenshots whenever possible.

Comment: You intentionally cast the `bool` array to a `char*` and assign `char` values. Of course this prevents a normal conversion from `char` to `bool` which would convert any non-zero value to 1 (= `true`). If you assign to `X[i]` instead of `pos[i]` you will see the value `1` as expected.

Comment: 'Why does a hole appear in my foot when I shoot it?', is basically what you are asking. If you force the compiler to form invalid booleans, you get undefined behaviour, so just don't do that.